# How to make cpu0 offline?

Tags: cpu

I want to make cpu0 offline. I have dual core laptop. I can make cpu1 offline ( using offline file ) but can't make cpu0 offline. How to do this ?

Comment: Are you trying to take cpu0 offline after taking cpu1 offline, or are you trying to do this separately?

Comment: No. I want to make cpu0 offline only. ( while keeping cpu1 online )

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/299780/taking-the-cores-offline

Comment: compile kernel with CONFIG_BOOTPARAM_HOTPLUG_CPU0 enabled. more details can be found here: https://events.static.linuxfound.org/sites/events/files/lcjpcojp13_fenghua.pdf

Answer (score 5):

to enable a cpu0

you can use this

```
echo 1 | sudo tee /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/online
```

and to disable

```
echo 0 | sudo tee /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/online
```

Comment: As @AIYA noted above, this only works if `CONFIG_BOOTPARAM_HOTPLUG_CPU0` is enabled in the kernel.

Answer (score 3):

I've also found, certain systems *cannot* disable CPU0.  I think usually this happens because the interrupt line is wired to CPU0, so the APIC cannot signal CPU1 on up (turning off CPU0 would cut off all interrupts and the system would lock up.)